# Why won't my external display detect its native resolution?

Tags: display, displayport, resolution

3 days ago I bought a Dell SE2219HX display (22") and connected it to my non-retina MBP mid 2012 model. I also own a HDMI extension that is to be connected to the display port but for some reason it won't work so I have the monitor connected to VGA instead and it works fine.

Except for one thing and that is that it won't detect and work at its native resolution which is `1920 * 1080`. When I first unboxed the monitor and connected it, it displayed natively. But yesterday after a fresh reboot, it didn't go beyond `1280 * 1024` and it displayed those settings as default. I had to reset the SMC and it came back again at `1920 * 1080`. But today when I thought the settings would be safely saved, the display again started up at `1280 * 1024`. I've set it to scaled display now by pressing the option button and selecting the actual native res but I doubt it will remember this setting upon the next boot and I cannot do a SMC reset every time. Is there a way this can be fixed, other than the alternative of using option in display settings?

EDIT: I also had an AOC 26" display connected couple of years ago with the same `1920 * 1080` res and had no such problems with it.